# Comments in XML at beginning of document

Tags: python, xml, parsing

my PYTHON xml parser fails if there´s a comment at the beginnging of an xml file like::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Script version: "1"-->
<!-- Date: "07052010"-->
<component name="abc">
<pp>
    ....
</pp>
</component>
```

is it illegal to place a comment like this?

EDIT:

well it´s not throwing an error but the DOM module will fail and not recognize the child nodes:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
sub_tree = dom.parse('xyz.xml')
for component in sub_tree.firstChild.childNodes:
    print(component)
```

I cannot acces the child nodes; sub_tree.firstChild.childNodes returns an empty list,but if I remove those 2 comments I can loop through the list and read the childnodes as usual!

EDIT:

Guys, this simple example is working and enough to figure it out. start your python shell and execute this small code above. Once it will output nothing and after deleting the comments it will show up the  node!

Comment: They're legal. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments and you should show the code that is is failing, and you should read the SO faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: This is legal XML however that does not mean all XML parsers will handle it. What parser are you using, what error is being returned and if possible please post a code snippet of what you are doing.

Comment: `<ppe> ... </pp>` -- Please don't type from memory; show us an actual small document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
sub_tree = dom.parse('xyz.xml')
print sub_tree.children
```

You will see what is your problem:

```
>>> print sub_tree.childNodes
[<DOM Comment node " Script ve...">, <DOM Comment node " Date: "07...">, <DOM Element: component at 0x7fecf88c>]
```

firstChild will obviously pick up the first child, which is a comment and doesn't have any children of its own.
You could iterate over the children and skip all comment nodes.

Or you could ditch the DOM model and use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), which is so much nicer to work with. :)

Comment: antoher question: there are 3 nodes: 2 comments and one element node.
but where´s the root element? valid xml files are allowed to have only ONE root element! Or does the parser treat comments differently?
I think there must be 1 parent element!

Comment: ElementTree is able to parse such XML, but it doesn't seem to preserve it.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal; from XML 1.0 [Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments):

> 2.5 Comments
>
> [Definition: Comments may appear
>   anywhere in a document outside other
>   markup; in addition, they may appear
>   within the document type declaration
>   at places allowed by the grammar. They
>   are not part of the document's
>   character data; an XML processor MAY,
>   but need not, make it possible for an
>   application to retrieve the text of
>   comments. For compatibility, the
>   string " -- " (double-hyphen) MUST NOT
>   occur within comments.] Parameter
>   entity references MUST NOT be
>   recognized within comments.

Answer (score 1):

To get better answers, show us (a) a small complete Python script and (b) a small complete XML document that together demonstrate the unexpected behaviour.

Have you considered using ElementTree?

Answer (score 0):

That should be legal as long as the XML declaration is on the first line.